# opencv video capture and camera access on virtual machine

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, virtual-machine, video-capture

I am trying to capture images in real time using the webcam on my computer.
I am running Ubuntu using virtual box, and I am aware that I need to set the USB setting to be able to use the webcam, but do I still need to install a webcam driver ? if yes how do I do that !!

I installed 
virtualbox 5.0.6
ubuntu 14.04.3

and I am running a windows 10 machine

here is the code I am running, and I am getting "ERROR: Could not access the camera!" ..

could you please help !

```
// Get access to the webcam.
void initWebcam(VideoCapture &videoCapture, int cameraNumber)
{
    // Get access to the default camera.
    try {   
        videoCapture.open(cameraNumber);
    } catch (Exception &e) {}
    if ( !videoCapture.isOpened() ) {
        cerr << "ERROR: Could not access the camera!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Loaded camera " << cameraNumber << "." << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    const int DESIRED_CAMERA_WIDTH = 640;
    const int DESIRED_CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;    
    int cameraNumber = 0;  

    // Get access to the camera.
    VideoCapture camera;
    initWebcam(camera, cameraNumber);

    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, DESIRED_CAMERA_WIDTH);
    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, DESIRED_CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    while (true) {

        // Grab the next camera frame. Note that you can't modify camera frames.
        Mat cameraFrame;
        camera >> cameraFrame;
        if( cameraFrame.empty() ) {
            cerr << "ERROR: Couldn't grab the next camera frame." << endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        Mat displayedFrame = Mat(cameraFrame.size(), CV_8UC3);
        // DO SOME PROCESSING

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be answered.I am also having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. This was happened to me because my virtual machine didn't detect my webcam. I have installed cheese (a program which uses the webcam) and confirmed that thing. So, I have turn on the USB controllers on the virtual machine configuration. Then, running the virtual machine, I checked my webcam inside on Devices menu and everything began to work!.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an authorisation problem.
Try to run with sudo from command line.
Another problem could be that you select the wrong camera (e.g. you have a laptop and there is also the integrated camera on), you can have some hint on the device attached to the vm using 'dmesg | grep usb'